# Kotlin how to create a cache with objects that extend a single base class

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am wracking my brain and I havent been able to come up with a solution for this. I have been reading [Generics in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) and was trying to do some stuff but havent been able to find out.

I have a base interface `A`. `B` and `C` are interfaces that inherit `A`. `ObjB` actually inherits `B` and implements the methods. I am trying to create a cache of objects extending `A` and use retrieval to differentiate between `B` and `C` objects. Sadly, I have not been able to make much progress. I've tried using `out` in `A` but that led to other problems.

```
interface A<T> {
    fun value() : String
}

interface B : A<B> {
    fun valueB() : String
}

interface C : A<C> {
    fun valueC() : String
}

class ObjB : B {
    override fun value() : String {
        return "B"
    }
    override fun valueB() : String {
        return "objB"
    }
}

class AllTogether {
   val cache : ConcurrentHashMap<String, A<Any>> = ConcurrentHashMap()
   
   fun retrieveB(val: String) : B {
       // return cache.get(val)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic parameter in interfaces is never used, so you can remove it:

```
interface A {
    fun value() : String
}

interface B : A {
    fun valueB() : String
}

interface C : A {
    fun valueC() : String
}

class ObjB : B {
    override fun value(): String {
        return "B"
    }
    override fun valueB(): String {
        return "objB"
    }
}


class AllTogether {
    val cache: ConcurrentHashMap<String, A> = ConcurrentHashMap()

    fun retrieveB(key: String): B? {
        return cache[key] as? B
    }
}
```